# Kafka producer throwing TimeoutException: Expiring XX record(s) 600365 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

Tags: java, apache-kafka

My kafka producer is throwing TimeoutException: Expiring XX record(s) 600365 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time.

I am trying to design high throughput producer(spring-kafka version:2.2.4.RELEASE) with following configurations:

```
"batch.size": "131072",
"request.timeout.ms": "600000",
"linger.ms": "1000"
```

My producer is receiving very high no of message within a shot span of time. You can imagine i am sending 10lacs messages in one go, where each message size is around 6 kb. Using the above configuration i am able to reduce this error count to 12k, but was not able to remove it. I have tried using async calls, having thread count of 3, but no use.
Topic configuration:
Partition: 10
replication: 2
Can anyone suggest what should i do to remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `flush()` the producer on your own, within the timeout of "batch creation + **`linger.ms`** producer config" (with dot, not underscore. Use `ProducerConfig` constants...).

Otherwise, the producer memory buffer will "expire records" via a timeout (the time the producer will wait for more `send()` calls to append to its buffer).

Load is not a factor in the calculation / error.

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer, Appreciate for the quick response ! I read some contents over usage of flush(), so got to know that it would make the producer synchronous: PS: https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/wiki/FAQ#why-is-there-no-sync-produce-interface
Please do suggest here! Also FYI, We have tried multiple batch.size, linger and request.timeout.ms combinations already and we are using @async in the producer method.

Comment: Upon reaching `batch.size`, the producer becomes synchronous, anyway, ad flushing the buffer is done automatically. If you don't have enough frequent data to reach that size, you'll expect to see errors such as yours, so one solution is to flush on your own. Otherwise, reduce the batch size config below your average expected payload size (in bytes). Also, Spring does not use librdkafka; Java clients do have a sync send function, if you wanted to use it